# Select rows given priority to a column postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table product with id, name and warehouseId. I want to get all products but giving priority to a given warehouseId, i.e. if there is many products with the same name and different warehouseId return only the one with the warehouseId designated, and if the are many products with the same name, different warehouseId and none of the warehouseId matches the designated return any.

Example:

```
id  | name | warehouseId
-------------------------
 1  |  A   |    1
 2  |  A   |    2
 3  |  B   |    1
 4  |  B   |    3
```

With designated wharehouseId = 2 expected:

```
id  | name | warehouseId
-------------------------
 2  |  A   |    2
 3  |  B   |    1
```

How can achieve that in postgresql 14?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a case for `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (name)
       id, name, warehouseId
FROM tab
ORDER BY name, warehouseId = 2 DESC;
```

This relies on the fact that `TRUE > FALSE`.